# Structuring multi-module projects in SBT across multiple repositories

Tags: scala, sbt

We are using SBT and Ivy, but are having issues with multi-module projects. I am not sure if there is a better way of doing what we are attempting to do.

We have a parent module, which aggregates the submodules:

```
lazy val `foo-parent` = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(`foo-layout`,`foo-environment`,...)
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
```

And some submodules, e.g.:

```
lazy val `foo-layout` = Project("foo-layout", file("foo-layout"))
  .settings(commonSettings: _*)
  .settings(
    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      `...),
    name := "foo-layout"
  ).dependsOn(`foo-config`)
```

We have a core module of libraries, aggregated in `foo-parent`, all in the same git repo, and "implementation" modules for clients in separate repos. In the implementation modules we used to import the submodules as library dependencies e.g.:

```
libraryDependencies += "com.foo" %% "foo-layout" % foo_version
```

The problem with this was when changing anything in `foo-parent` you had to manually do `sbt publishLocal`, or set the modules as "module dependencies" in IntelliJ, which reset to using JARs every time the project is refreshed.

Now we have a symlink "foo-source" which is linked to the directory "foo-parent" in which all of the sub-modules reside, and have a somewhat wrong-feeling way of switching between using source and JARs.

```
val compileFooFromSource = false
lazy val foo_parent: Project = Project("foo-parent", file("foo-source"))
lazy val foo_dependencies = Seq("foo-environment", "foo-layout", ...)
lazy val test: Project = compileFooFromSource match {
  case false =>
    Project("test", file("."))
      .settings(artifactSettings: _*)
      .settings(
        libraryDependencies ++= foo_dependencies.map( mod =>
          ("com.foo" % mod % version.value)
        )
      )
  case true =>
    Project("test", file("."))
      .settings(artifactSettings: _*)
      .dependsOn(foo_dependencies.map(s => classpathDependency(s)): _*)

}
```

This approach relies on symlinks, which could cause problems for Windows developers or CI (we have to remember to change the source flag to false before committing, or CI will break.)
Is this the only way of having a multi-module project that is structured like this across multiple repos? Is there a more SBT "way"?

Comment: Any reason why not to create additional modules inside build.sbt and use `dependsOn`?

Comment: We can't create modules in the `parent` project because lots of separate client projects use that code. 
The big block above is from the client build.sbt, but the only way to create the `parent` module in that build.sbt is using a symlink as I have done?